# Image not being inserted into mysql database from php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert an image into mysql database from php. I am using the following code to do so.

```
$file=  file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
$sql="UPDATE  mainadmin set photo='$file' where id='$id'";
mysql_query($sql);
$_SESSION['photo']=$file;
```

But the image is not being inserted into mysql database. But its being properly stored in session variable and shown properly. But when i am going to get the image from database i saw previous image is still stored and no update was taken place in the database. Can anyone help me to find the mistake

Comment: Do you actually want to insert it into the database which requires column type `BLOB` or do you want to save it on the server?

Comment: I want to store in database and my column is of long blob type

Comment: Did you start the session? What is in `$id`?

Comment: Hello, Instead i am trying to insert $filei=$_FILES['file']['name'];. Though its inserting but probably storing the garbase value. and the inserted image is not being retrieved later

Comment: Yes i did start session

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Any idea on how to do the insertion? I tried with LOAD_FILe also. Didn't work

Comment: Thanks @tadman. I'll use PDO from now

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change the code this way, and make the database field photo to **BLOB** type

```
$fp = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r");  

if ($fp) {

     $content = fread($fp, $_FILES['file']['size']);

     fclose($fp);   

     $content = addslashes($content);     

     $sql="UPDATE  mainadmin set photo='$content' where id='$id'";

     mysql_query($sql);

     $_SESSION['photo']=$content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem.
Here is my updated code. Just using addSlashes() method solved the problem

```
    $file=  file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
    $filei=addslashes($file) ;
    $id=$_SESSION['id'];
    $sql="UPDATE  mainadmin set photo='$filei' where id='$id'";
    mysql_query($sql);
    $_SESSION['photo']=$file;
```